# Error while making SummarizedExperiment

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I want to make a SummarizedExperiment,
I have  the count table in this format in FeatureCount.txt

```
         SRR1554537 SRR1554538  SRR1554541  SRR1554535  SRR1554536  SRR1554539
1/2-SBSRNA4        39   66         72             23            16      7
A1BG               221  113        226           146             36   126
A1BG-AS1           393  296        527            276            39   258
A1CF                 8  7          5                1             0    4
A2LD1               97  208       171             181             72    110
```

I have the phenotype Data in this format:

```
              SampleName    RUN Age sex tissue  disease
SRR1554537  R3452_DLPFC_polyA_RNAseq_total  SRR1554537  -0.384  female  DLPFC   control
SRR1554538  R3462_DLPFC_polyA_RNAseq_total  SRR1554538  -0.4027 female  DLPFC   control
SRR1554541  R3485_DLPFC_polyA_RNAseq_total  SRR1554541  -0.3836 male    DLPFC   control
SRR1554535  R2869_DLPFC_polyA_RNAseq_total  SRR1554535  41.58   male    DLPFC   control
SRR1554536  R3098_DLPFC_polyA_RNAseq_total  SRR1554536  44.17   female  DLPFC   control
SRR1554539  R3467_DLPFC_polyA_RNAseq_total  SRR1554539  36.5    female  DLPFC   control
```

Here is my code:

```
count_feature <- as.matrix(read.table("featureCount.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
phenoData <- read.csv("Pheno_Data.csv", header = TRUE)
col_data <- DataFrame(phenoData)

row_data <- relist(GRanges(), vector("list", length= nrow(count_feature)))
mcols(row_data) <- rownames(count_feature)

Brain_Es <- SummarizedExperiment( assays = list(feature_Count= feature_Count), rowRanges = row_data, colData = col_data)
```

> Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("X", "SRR1554537", "SRR1554538",  : 
>     invalid rownames length

Can you explain the error?

Comment: I've noticed that you're using the `SummarizedExperiment` package from Bioconductor. Could you please note the packages you've loaded in your question?

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it by transposing the counts table

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with `row_data`, but it's clearly not working. You already have gene names from the count table. Why not do

```
Brain_Es <- SummarizedExperiment(assays = list(counts = count_feature), colData = col_data, rowData = rownames(count_feature));
```

Have a look at `?SummarizedExperiment`, and at the examples given [here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/vignettes/SummarizedExperiment/inst/doc/SummarizedExperiment.html#constructing-a-summarizedexperiment) in section "Constructing a SummarizedExperiment".